# Can I return a different resource from a POST request?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I am writing a RESTful web service API. I am going to post an `Answer` resource to a mechanical question. When I do this I want to know if I answered correct or not. For this I have a `Result` resource.

Is it wrong to return a different resource that the one you POSTed in a HTTP request?

Example:
`POST /mechanical-questions/4/answers` - shoud return result.

The answer will be saved on the server, but so will the result. Should I return a HttpStatus 20x code together with a Location header indicating where I can find the quiz result or the answer, and what should the response entity be? The created answer or the quiz result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there is no one 'correct' answer to this.  I think you are right in saying that you should not return a RESULT object to an endpoint that receives an ANSWER object. To me I think it is a bit strange to return the Location: header. It should be up to the consuming client what they want to do with the ANSWER object after creation. What I sometimes see is a location property in the POST response object.

So you have a request like this

```
{
  'answer' : 'I hope I am correct'
}
```

And a response like this

```
{
   'id' : 12345
   'answer' : 'I hope I am correct'
   'result_id' : 68472
   'result_location' : '/mechanical-questions/4/result/68472'
}
```

This allows the client to determine the flow after a user makes an answer - maybe they immediately do a GET for the result and display it, or maybe the bundle up a multi-get response after a series of questions are answered.

Comment: Yes, that make sense.But do I need to include the answer data? Can I just add the result_location? Or is this bad?

Comment: When I think of RESTful API I consider each endpoint representing a single resource or a list of resources. When you POST to an endpoint to create a resource, you should return the full resource you just created. As I emphasized in my answer, it should be up to the consuming client what they want to do with the API. By returning the full answer object, you allow the client to do something like store the answer ID returned and creating a mapping table in their application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should certainly return an OK code since it is a completely valid situation. It is nor a server error or bad request or something like that.

As for the response entity, that really depends on your business logic, at least from my point of view. It's a bit controversial between developers. If you want your client to get a correct answer in either case then just put the answer itself. If the client should maybe have a few tries before he gets a answer, than maybe put a URL to the response entity. You could even do both...